# Put block before footer with only xml

Tags: magento, layout, block

I do not wan't to edit the template files at all, I just want to put a block above the footer with local.xml and using a custom block file or a static block from the CMS..

Is this possible?

I have tried adding this but I am not able to use footer.before.before since it is not using the `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`

```
   <default>
      <reference name="content" >
        <block type="core/text_list" name="customblock" as="customblock" after="-" translate="label">
        <label>Custom Block</label>
        </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="customblockreference">
          <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Answer (score 3):

Which Magento version and layout (1column, 2columns etc.) are you using?

In latest versions you could use the `footer_before` position for this.

```
    <default>
      <reference name="footer_before">
        <reference name="customblockreference">
          <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="customblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
```